# Как получить адрес метки, по которой кликнул?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Добавил метки на яндекс карты, и необходимо получить адрес метки, на которую кликнул. Я пытался получить хотя бы её id, но почему то не работает:

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var map;
    ymaps.geolocation.get().then(function (res) {
        var mapContainer = $('#map'),
        bounds = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy'),
        mapState = ymaps.util.bounds.getCenterAndZoom(
            bounds,
            [mapContainer.width(), mapContainer.height()]
        );
        createMap(mapState);
    }, function (e) {
        createMap({
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        });
    });

    function createMap (state) {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', state);
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            clusterize: true,
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true
        });
        this.objectManager.objects.events.add(['click'], function (e) {
            var objectId = e.get('objectId'); 
            console.log(objectId);
        });

        objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
        objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            objectManager.add(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Есть что-то в консоли? Или клик совсем не обрабатывается?

Comment: В консоль ничего не выводится. В каждой метке у меня есть данные которые выводятся при клике, но в консоль при этом, id не приходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже вы перепутали. Вы обрабатываете клик на маркер, а сами кликаете на кластер. Добавьте обработчик кластера:

```
this.objectManager.clusters.events.add(['click'], function (e) {
    var objectId = e.get('objectId'); 
    console.log(objectId);
});
```

При увеличении карты у вас появятся метки. Клик по ним вы уже обрабатываете.

Запись свойства метки в input:

```
this.objectManager.objects.events.add(['click'], function (e) {
    var content = objectManager.objects.getById(e.get("objectId")).properties['balloonContentBody'];
    document.getElementById('someInputId').value = content;
});
```

Comment: Всё равно. Добавил ваш код и ничего не изменилось, новых данных не получил

Comment: @KevinSmash. Вот посмотрите:https://jsfiddle.net/tsb275vn/2/. Все работает

Comment: Действительно, спасибо вам! Вы не знаете как теперь это значение можно сохранить? Или работать с ним

Comment: Сохранить куда? И что вы подразумевает под работать с ним? Все зависит от задач.

Comment: Задача считать адрес из выбранной метки. Он в файле data.json в такой форме у каждой метки: "balloonContentBody": "<p class=\"address\">Адрес: обл Восточно-Казахстанская, г Семей, ул Шакарима, дом 60</p> Его нужно передать в поле input

Comment: @KevinSmash Добавил в ответ.